# Change values in a list using a for loop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I currently have some code that reads like this:

```
letters = {
10 : "A",
11 : "B",
12 : "C",
13 : "D",
14 : "E",
15 : "F"
}
vallist = [rd1, rd2, gd1, gd2, bd1, bd2]
for i in vallist:
    if i >= 10:
        i = letters[i]
```

What I want to happen is the for loop to iterate through `vallist` and replace any value that is greater than 10 with its corresponding letter. However, my current code just changes `i` and not the original value in the list. For example, if `rd1` is set to 15, the code runs through and `i` is set to `"F"`, but `rd1` does not change to `"F"`, and instead just stays as 15. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For each iteration of the `for` loop the variable `i` is assigned with just a copy of the value of an item in `vallist`, so changes made to `i` won't be reflected in `i`.

You should update the items of `i` via index, which you can generate with the `enumerate` function:

```
for index, value in enumerate(vallist):
    if value >= 10:
        vallist[index] = letters[value]
```

Comment: I think this statement is not correct: "[...] the variable `i` is assigned with just a copy of the value of an item in `vallist`, [...]". According to [Ned Batchelder's guide](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) "Assignment never copies data". A for-loop is an assignment as well; in this case it makes `i` refer to a value already referenced by an item in `vallist`. It's the line  `i = letters[i]` where now `i` refers to another value, in this case the value of `letters[i]`, e.g. the string "A". There is no copying involved in the author's code example.

Answer (score 2):

```
rd1, rd2, gd1, gd2, bd1, bd2 = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 9
letters = {
10 : "A",
11 : "B",
12 : "C",
13 : "D",
14 : "E",
15 : "F"
}
vallist = [rd1, rd2, gd1, gd2, bd1, bd2]
for index, value in enumerate(vallist):
    if value >= 10 and value <= 15:
        vallist[index] = letters[value]
print(vallist)
```

As mentioned in the other comment you need both the index and the value while looping over your vallist. so you can replace the value on the index with the value in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(vallist)):
    if vallist[i] >= 10:
        vallist[i] = letters[i]
```

Because in your case i is just a copy of the current item in vallist. But this way i will be an index, so you can modify your original list throught it.

Answer (score 0):

actually i is the reference of that element of array and the value changes will not be affected to that element , instead try this,

# iterating through every index of array

```
for i in range(len(vallist)):
 if vallist[i] >= 10 and vallist[i]<=15:
      vallist[i] = letters[vallist[i]]
```